# Why my PHP session's variable doesn't work anymore?

Tags: php, session, session-variables

i've a web platform written in PHP. In this platform we have a login and a payment page that have ever worked fine, but now the PHP session's variables doesn't work anymore. The codebase it's the same.
The /tmp folder exists, i've write permission and the session start correctly but every time i set a session variable and switch to the next page the superglobal array is empty.

This is the login script. Attention on line 49

```
<?php 
include_once('database.php');
include_once('const.php');
include_once('functions.php');

if( isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) ){
    $email = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
    $password = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST['password']));

    $db = new Database();
    $conn = $db->getConnection();

    if( accountAlreadyExists($email, "ANAGRAFICA_SOCI") ){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `wcksdc5_DWH`.ANAGRAFICA_SOCI WHERE EMAIL = :email ;";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(":email", $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        try{
            $stmt->execute();
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo ' Error: ' . $e->getMessage();   
            echo ' Line: ' . $e->getLine();   
            echo ' File: ' . $e->getFile();
        }
        if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
            $res = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $dbPass = $res['PASSWORD'];
            if(password_verify($password, $dbPass)){
                if(!session_start()){
                    die('Impossibile creare sessione..');
                }
                $_SESSION['userLogged'] = true;
                $_SESSION['nome'] = $res['NOME'];
                $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
                header('Location: ../dashboard.php');
            }else{
                die('Password errata, riprovare.');
            }
        }else{
            die("Errore, se il problema persiste contattare l'amministratore di sistema..");
        }
    }else if( accountAlreadyExists($email, "UTENTI_DA_APPROVARE") ){
        $var = checkTmpPaymentStatus($email);
        if( $var ){
            echo "L'account è in attesa di approvazione da parte del maestro. Si prega di riprovare più tardi";
        }else if( !$var ){
            if(!session_start()){
                die('Impossibile creare sessione di pagamento..');
            }
            $_SESSION['userLogged'] = true;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            header('Location: ../membership-fee.php');
            exit();
        }else{
            "Trovato valore non conosciuto";
        }
    }else{
        die("L'account non esiste. Si prega di ricontrollare le credenziali");
    }
    
}else{
    die("Non sono presenti tutti i dati richiesti per performare l'operazione");
}
?>
```

And this is the next page

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
include_once('./php/database.php');
include_once('./php/const.php');
include_once('./php/functions.php');
include_once('./php/json-fn.php');

if(!isset($_SESSION['userLogged']) || $_SESSION['userLogged'] != true){
  die("Non possiedi i privilegi per visitare questa sezione");
}
?>
```

Comment: Try to place `session_start();` at the top of the page just after `<?php` tag and before any other code or text. It will save you a lot of trouble in the future. Also, all the pages where you want to access `session` should have it in the top

Answer (score 0):

**Similar to what i coded, you have to include this in all of your pages**

```
<?php
   session_start();
   $title=$_SESSION['username'];
   $pic=$_SESSION['pic'];
   if(!risset($_SESSION['username']))
      header('Location:index.php');
   ?>
```

*You can start your html code right after this*

**To create a session , you can use the code below**

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['pic']=$row['propic'];
```

**To destroy a session (log out )**

```
<?php
   session_start();
   session_destroy();
   header('Location:index.php');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I don't see how this code can help me

Comment: always post what you tried and the code snippet when asking the quesion